# Concatenating hex bytes and strings in JavaScript while preserving bytes

Tags: javascript, utf-8, hex, concatenation

I would like to concatenate a hex value and a string using JavaScript.

```
var hexValue = 0x89;
var png = "PNG";
```

The string "PNG" is equivalent to the concatenation of `0x50`, `0x4E`, and `0x47`.

Concatenating `hexValue` and `png` via

```
var concatHex = String.fromCharCode(0x89) + String.fromCharCode(0x50) 
              + String.fromCharCode(0x4E) + String.fromCharCode(0x47);
```

...give a result with a byte count of 5 because of the first hex value needing a control character:

```
C2 89 50 4E 47
```

I am working with raw image data where I have `hexValue` and `png` and need to concatenate them without this control character being included.

1. Is there a way to trim off the control character?
2. Given I have an array of bytes, is there a better way to concatenate them and a string while preserving the bytes?

Comment: i know this sounds weird but look for an older example of using binary ajax in firefox 3 and you'll find the loop code you need...

Comment: @dandavis, do you have a link to that? I already have my hex and strings as vars.

Comment: @Mat your string are in utf8 encoding right?

Comment: @emcas88, yes. That's safe to assume.

Comment: i was talking about a loop body of binChar = char % 255

Comment: @dandavis - Would you mind explaining that a little more, possibly in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well i was investigating and i found that in javascript to achieve this eficienly JavaScript typed arrays is used.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br212485(v=vs.94).aspx

Here i wrote a code (not tested) to perform what you want:

```
var png = "PNG";
var hexValue = 0x89;
var lenInBytes = (png.Length + 1) * 8; //left an extra space to concat hexValue

var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(lenInBytes); //create chunk of memory whose bytes are all pre-initialized to 0
var int8View = new Int8Array(buffer); //treat this memory like int8

for(int i = 0; i < png.Length ; i++)
    int8View[i] = png[i]  //here convert the png[i] to bytes

//at this point we have the string png as array of bytes

    int8View[png.Length] = hexValue //here the concatenation is performed
```

Well hope it helps.