# Concatenating two hex values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hex

I am trying to concatenate two hex values, but I have actually no idea where to begin..

As example:

a = 0x01
b = 0x23

output = 0x123

What could be the best the best solution for this particular problem?
Please let me know :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762605/concatenating-hex-bytes-and-strings-in-javascript-while-preserving-bytes

Comment: Why do you want to concatenate them? Are you sure you have concatenated them properly in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a string using [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method and concatenate.

```js
var a = 0x01,
  b = 0x23;

// as number
console.log(
  parseInt(a.toString(16) + b.toString(16), 16).toString(16)
)

// as string
console.log(
  a.toString(16) + b.toString(16)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that when b had a leading 0 (0x05) it would drop the zero.  this fixed it for me.

```
var a = 0x01,
  b = 0x03;

// returns 13
console.log(
  a.toString(16) + b.toString(16)
)

// returns 0103
console.log(
  ("00"+k.toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("00"+k.toString(16)).slice(-2)
);
```